# AWS CodeDeploy :bucket option must not contain a forward-slash (/)

Tags: aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I am kicking off a deployment from aws-cli:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" deploy create-deployment --application-name App.Web --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --deployment-group-name Development-Staging-UAT --region us-west-2 --description "App.Web" --s3-location bucket=app-artifacts/development,bundleType=zip,key=Publish.zip
```

This does kick off a deploy but end with error in the DownloadBundle section:

```
:bucket option must not contain a forward-slash (/)
```

Revision location
**s3://app-artifacts/development/Publish.zip**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" deploy create-deployment --application-name App.Web --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --deployment-group-name Development-Staging-UAT --region us-west-2 --description "App.Web" --s3-location bucket=app-artifacts,bundleType=zip,key=development/Publish.zip
```

Need to removed the /development from bucket and add it part of the key